# Is it possible to add an item to an existing web view context menu in android?

Tags: android

I want to customize the Web view Context Menu(Open, Open in new Window, Save, Copy, Copy Link..) (Long-Click on Web item or Web URL)

Is it possible to edit the global context menu(Add new Item to existing Context Menu) which is provided by the android?

Answer (score 0):

Only supposing here but you might want to override [`View.OnLongClickListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html)

```
public class MyWebView extends WebView{
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v){
       //your own code here
       //return true if you want to prevent default behavior
       //return super.onLongClick(v) if you want to force default behavior

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Laurent.
Implementing this would let me change the context menu for a single view. I want to change for all the webviews,
if I Implement new option for myWebsite, Will it be available for all urls I open with browser?

Comment: @SrikanthChilukuri ok, I get you now: you want to modify the behavior of the stock web browser, not create your own application. I doubt that you can do this but I'm not sure of it: popup menus such as 'share' depend on what apps you have. If that is possible it will be by providing an `Intent` in the `<intent-filter>` section of your manifest.